# Big query cron job without webservice

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, google-bigquery

Is it possible to run script which proccess user data without running google app engine webservice?

With smaller scripts it works well but when my scripts last about 40minutes I'm getting error: `DeadlineExceededError`

My temporary fix was to use windows scheduler on windows VM and command line with python script

**Edit: code added**

```
jobs = []
jobs_status = []
jobs_error = []
# The project id whose datasets you'd like to list
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'project'
scope = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
         'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds')

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secrets.json', scope)

# Create the bigquery api client
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

def load_logs(source):
    body = {"rows": [
        {"json": source}
    ]}

    response = service.tabledata().insertAll(
        projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
        datasetId='test',
        tableId='test_log',
        body=body).execute()
    return response

def job_status():
    for job in jobs:
        _jobId = job['jobReference']['jobId']
        status = service.jobs().get(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER, jobId=_jobId).execute()
        jobs_status.append(status['status']['state'])
        if 'errors' in status['status'].keys():
            query = str(status['configuration']['query']['query'])
            message = str(status['status']['errorResult']['message'])
            jobs_error.append({"query": query, "message": message})
    return jobs_status


def check_statues():
    while True:
        if all('DONE' in job for job in job_status()):
            return


def insert(query, tableid, disposition):
    job_body = {
     "configuration": {
      "query": {
       "query": query,
       "useLegacySql": True,
       "destinationTable": {
        "datasetId": "test",
        "projectId": "project",
        "tableId": tableid
       },
       "writeDisposition": disposition
      }
     }
    }

    r = service.jobs().insert(
        projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER,
        body=job_body).execute()
    jobs.append(r)
    return r



class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        query = "SELECT * FROM [gdocs_users.user_empty]"
        insert(query, 'users_data_p1', "WRITE_TRUNCATE")
        check_statues()
        query = "SELECT * FROM [gdocs_users.user_empty]"
        insert(query, 'users_data_p2', "WRITE_TRUNCATE")
        query = "SELECT * FROM [gdocs_users.user_%s]"
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            if i <= 600:
                insert(query % str(i).zfill(4), 'users_data_p1', "WRITE_APPEND")
            else:
                insert(query % str(i).zfill(4), 'user_data_p2', "WRITE_APPEND")
        for error in jobs_error:
            load_logs(error)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default App Engine services uses [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes), which has a 60 second limit for HTTP requests and a 10 minute limit for task queue requests. If you change your service to use basic or manual scaling, then your task queue request can run for up to 24 hours.

It sounds like you likely only need one instance for this work, so perhaps create a second [service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) in addition to the default service. In a subfolder create a `bqservice` folder with  the following `app.yaml` settings that use basic scaling with a max of one instance:

```
# bqsservice/app.yaml
# Possibly use a separate service for your BQ code than
# the rest of your app:
service: bqservice
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
# Keep low memory/cost B1 class?
instance_class: B1
# Limit max services to 1 to keep costs down. There is an
# 8 instance hour limit to the free tier. This option still
# scales to 0 when not in use.
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

# Handlers:
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Then create a [`cron.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref) in the same service to schedule your script to run. With my example configuration above you would put your BigQuery logic into a main.py file with a WSGI app defined within it:

```
# bqservice/main.py
import webapp2

class CronHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
       # Handle your cron work
       # ....

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    #('/', MainPage),  # If you needed other handlers
    ('/mycron', CronHandler),
], debug=True)
```

You could work this all into the default service if you don't plan on using the App Engine app for anything else. If you do this in addition to the default service, you'll need to deploy something to the default service first, even if it is just a simple `app.yaml` with static files.

Comment: Thanks BrettJ! This solution could work - but note that App Engine is doing no work while waiting for BigQuery to return. A better way is to return as soon as the job is enqueued, and then come back later to see if the job is done.

Comment: @BrettJ thank you for help. I would like to add also If someone will try that you'll have to add `target: your_service` in your `cron.yaml` to determine service you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Most BigQuery operations can run asynchronously. Can you show us your code?

For example, from the Python BigQuery docs:

```
def query(query):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query)

    query_job.begin()
    query_job.result()  # Wait for job to complete
```

That's an asynchronous job, and the code is choosing to wait for the query to complete. Instead of waiting, get the job id after `begin()`. You can enqueue a task to run later with the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks), to check for the results of that job.

Comment: I had to create service because I have federated tables (from gsuit) which weren't working with python API and as you see I'm running them asynchronously by inserting jobs

Comment: Yeah - looking at the code you should not `check_statues()`. Then the function will return as soon as the job is inserted. Then come back later to check for the result of that job id.

Comment: But I have some queries below and I'm running them when my inserts are done. As I read in documentation error is raised after 60s requesting timeout so the question is that app engine is a good place for such kind of scripts or It's rather for small backend stuff?

Comment: Yes. App Engine is good. Just run things in asynchronous scripts.

Comment: I'm using `check_statues` few time in my script after loop. Process again queries with errors, save them to tables with logs. Then I run few different queries which need previous jobs to be done. I changed scalling to basic and problem gone because my script lasts around 40mins.